# NGINX turns POST requests to GET in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, nginx

I have a Spring Boot application that sends a POST request to an endpoint on my server in port 8090. My Java controller is:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/decision", method = POST)
@ResponseBody
public void setDecision(HttpEntity<String> httpEntity, @RequestHeader("Authorization") String auth) throws Exception {
   // controller implementation
}
```

I have the nginx in SSL configuration that proxies the request to port 8090 in default-ssl file:

```
 location /my_endpoint
{
    auth_basic off;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8090;
    proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

}
```

When I send the request with postman and I open the access logs of nginx I see the following output:

```
My.IP.Address -  [31/Aug/2018:08:49:59 +0200] "POST /my_endpoint HTTP/1.1" 301 185 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.1.1"
My.IP.Address -  [31/Aug/2018:08:50:00 +0200] "GET /my_endpoint HTTP/1.1" 405 163 "http://MyServer/my_endpoint" "PostmanRuntime/7.1.1"
```

So I don't understand why while I send a POST request nginx makes it a GET request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP [status code 301](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) is used for permanent URL redirection. After the POST request is completed you're redirected to another page. That's where the second GET comes from.

Comment: Thanks! So every time I proxy a request I will always have this issue? I mean: I send a POST and 301 occurs due to the redirection to proxy 8090 which then asks a GET ?

Comment: It's not about the proxy, it's about the response. Your setDecision method just responds with a redirect.

Comment: How is that possible? It's a simple POST. Redirect was supposed to occur in the proxy pass right  ?